# surefire results not showing in the test tab of gitlab CI/CD

Tags: java, junit, continuous-integration, gitlab, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a java-maven application and I am trying to display my junit results on gitlab as shown in the gitlab help here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html#viewing-junit-test-reports-on-gitlab

I added the `maven-surefire-plugin` in the pom build and the `maven-surefire-report-plugin` in the pom reporting section. I checked that it works because the `surefire-report.html` is correctly created in my local target repository, with the test results.

Then i configured my gitlabci.yaml by adding the last lines:

```yaml
image: "maven"
before_script:
  - cd gosecuri
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - run
job_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn compile
job_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn package
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - gosecuri/target/*.war
    expire_in: 1 week
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
```

The pipeline succeeds. In gitlab i have the message "There are no tests to show." in the job tests tab, and in the console I have this warning: **target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml: no matching files**

What am I missing? Thanks

PS: i'm running in gitlab.com Saas free plan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after docs you mentioned there is [Enabling the feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html#enabling-the-feature) paragraph.

> This feature comes with the **:junit_pipeline_view feature** flag disabled
>   by default.

Looks like feature is disabled on public gitlab.com. If you launch your instance of GitLab you can enable it.

Update: Path to reports was incorrect: `target/...` should be `gosecuri/target/...`

Comment: so you mean that everything that is in the gitlab help page is not working on gitlab.com saas? I was thinking the target repository is in the gitignore, does it have anything to do with the problem? I also added a console output that i had not seen before (see edit), maybe  i have to exclude the surefire-reports from the gitignore?

Comment: Your original description said that there are no relevant logs to the issue. Find out the proper path and update the pipeline to verify. I'd also ask gitlab admin if feature is enabled or not and if they plan to enable it.

Comment: yes sorry for that i had not checked the full log. but it's a warning, not a pipeline failure. And he XML files correctly appear in my local eclipse..

Comment: I'm looking at paths and artifacts are in `gosecuri/target/*.war` and report in `target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml`. Shouldn't this be: `gosecuri/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml`?

Comment: yep, that was the problem. displaying correct output now! many thanks. Maybe adapt your answer to match the solution :-)